# Why do some tennis broadcasts show the player's country next to their name?

Tags: tennis

For example, see this screenshot of the broadcast of the men's final from the 2018 Australian Open, between Roger Federer and Marin Cilic. https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DUoA7E-VMAMDD0C.jpg

They show the player's country flag next to their name. I noticed that not all tournaments will do this, it depends on the people broadcasting the match.

I can understand if it was an Olympic event or something like the Davis Cup, where the players are representing and playing for their countries. However, in most other instances, tennis is an individual sport, and the player is representing and playing solely for themselves, so knowing their nationality is unnecessary.

My questions:

1. Why do the broadcasts show this information? What purpose does it serve?
2. Why do some broadcasts show it, but some do not?

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you exactly why, but it's not specific to tennis.  It appears that US broadcasts will show this on other sports competed by individuals.  In particular, country can also bee seen for some auto racing, golf, and cycling broadcasts.

[image]
[image]

For many sports, it's somewhat common to see a player's birthplace or hometown listed.  I can speculate that's it's simply easy-to-determine information about an individual that they can show to help viewers gain better familiarity with them.  It seems a small step to move from there to showing a country if there's a sufficient number of participants that would make such a graphic entertaining.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input! I figured that this was common in other individual sports, but I used tennis as the example since that's the only sport I'm familiar with. I didn't think that a player's nationality was important or even relevant in individual sports, but I guess enough people do care.